# OpenSSL JNI FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface

I am trying to build JNI project and do encryption and decryption using openssl. I got the below error. What does it mean? when do we get such errors? and how to resolve it?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.

  > Build command failed.
  >   Error while executing process C:\android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\SampleJni\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a --target native-lib}
  >   [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
  >   [2/2] Linking CXX shared library ........\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so
  >   FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=C:/android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=14 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot C:/android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ........\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libssl.a -llog -lm "C:/android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'signal'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'tcgetattr'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_expand_block: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_compress_block: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_free: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_free: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_finish: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_finish: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_init: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit_'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_init: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit_'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_ctrl: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_ctrl: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit_'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
  >   ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit_'
  >   clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  >   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Below sharing the app's build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.openssl"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: The zlib issues could probably be resolved either by linking against zlib, or - if you don't need compression in openssl - reconfigure openssl with `no-zlib`. The other issues could probably be solved by reconfiguring openssl with `no-ui-console` if you're using openssl 1.1.1. If you're using openssl 1.0.x you could try raising your `minSdkVersion` to 21. If that's not an option you might have to modify your makefile for openssl to exclude the problematic source file (ui_openssl.c etc), and you might also have to add some configuration options (e.g. `no-err`).

Comment: openssl version is  1.1.0f  and for more details.

https://github.com/leenjewel/openssl_for_ios_and_android/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp

In native-lib.cpp, I have added encryption and decryption JNI Wrapper methods. 
JNI Wrapper reference link : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption